# Android sqLite.. Application unfortunately has stopped

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am Creating SqLite Application ... the application is launched perfectly but when I fill all EditText Fields And Click On The Add Button.. The Application has stopped.. this message popups..

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.database;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    EditText first,last,age,classc;
    Button add,view;

    String FirstName;
    String LastName;
    String Class;
    String Age;

    sqLit myDB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDB = new sqLit(this);

        Link();
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                xmlToVar();
                Integer flag=myDB.insertValue(FirstName, LastName, Class, Age);
                if (flag==1)
                {
                    Context context=MainActivity.this;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Record Added" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Context context=MainActivity.this;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occured" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void Link()
    {
        first=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFirst);
        last=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLast);
        classc=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editClass);
        age=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
        add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.Add);
        view=(Button) findViewById(R.id.ViewAll);
    }

    public void xmlToVar()
    {
        FirstName = first.getText().toString();
        LastName = last.getText().toString();
        Class = classc.getText().toString();
        try
        {
            Age = age.getText().toString();
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

sqLit.java

```
package com.example.database;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.text.Editable;

public class sqLit extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public static final String DB_NAME="student12.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="class1";

    public static final String COL_1="ROLLNO";
    public static final String COL_2="FirstName";
    public static final String COL_3="LastName";
    public static final String COL_4="Class";
    public static final String COL_5="Age";




    public sqLit(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +COL_1 + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"+COL_2 + " TEXT,"+COL_3 + " TEXT,"+COL_4 + " TEXT,"+COL_5 + " TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("Drop Table If Exist" + TABLE_NAME );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Integer insertValue(String firstName, String lastName, String Class, String Age)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentV = new ContentValues();
        contentV.put(COL_2, firstName);
        contentV.put(COL_3, lastName);
        contentV.put(COL_4, Class);
        contentV.put(COL_5, Age);
        long isInserted = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentV);
        if (isInserted == -1){
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
        }




}
```

Logcat

```
06-11 20:28:40.925: W/dalvikvm(25232): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f2b288)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE class1(ROLLNO INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,FirstName TEXT,LastName TEXT,Class TEXT,Age TEXT)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at com.example.database.sqLit.onCreate(sqLit.java:35)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at com.example.database.sqLit.insertValue(sqLit.java:48)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at com.example.database.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-11 20:28:40.925: E/AndroidRuntime(25232):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 20:28:40.944: D/dalvikvm(25232): GC_CONCURRENT freed 203K, 5% free 6173K/6471K, paused 13ms+0ms, total 16ms
```

Thanks Guys.. :)

Comment: I think it should be `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: did you try to read the error message?

Comment: @njzk2 a fault everyone can happen...Easy to overlook :)

Comment: overlooking reading the error message?

Comment: overlooking that he swaps to words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to re-shuffle the SQL autoincrement location?

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+COL_2 + " TEXT,"+COL_3 + " TEXT,"+COL_4 + " TEXT,"+COL_5 + " TEXT)");
```

Edit:

Actually, I may have been over complicating. It appears (according to the SQL Lite documentation at http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1) that:

> "If you declare a column of a table to be INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then
>   whenever you insert a NULL into that column of the table, the NULL is
>   automatically converted into an integer which is one greater than the
>   largest value of that column over all other rows in the table, or 1 if
>   the table is empty."

So you may be okay to leave out AUTOINCREMENT altogether as long as you insert nulls in there later on.